# DNS which returns 2 or more responses

Tags: python, sockets, dns, network-programming

I'm trying to use fake-dns server to test my code, problem is I need it to send 2 or more responses (response content isn't important). I'm using the following python code which I found in github but I couldn't find a way to make it send the response twice. Can you assist? Code is:

```
import socket

class DNSQuery:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data=data
    self.dominio=''

    tipo = (ord(data[2]) >> 3) & 15   # Opcode bits
    if tipo == 0:                     # Standard query
      ini=12
      lon=ord(data[ini])
      while lon != 0:
        self.dominio+=data[ini+1:ini+lon+1]+'.'
        ini+=lon+1
        lon=ord(data[ini])

  def respuesta(self, ip):
    packet=''
    if self.dominio:
      packet+=self.data[:2] + "\x81\x80"
      packet+=self.data[4:6] + self.data[4:6] + '\x00\x00\x00\x00'   # Questions and Answers Counts
      packet+=self.data[12:]                                         # Original Domain Name Question
      packet+='\xc0\x0c'                                             # Pointer to domain name
      packet+='\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x3c\x00\x04'             # Response type, ttl and resource data length -> 4 bytes
      packet+=str.join('',map(lambda x: chr(int(x)), ip.split('.'))) # 4bytes of IP
    return packet

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ip='192.168.1.1'
  print 'pyminifakeDNS:: dom.query. 60 IN A %s' % ip

  udps = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  udps.bind(('',53))

  try:
    while 1:
      data, addr = udps.recvfrom(1024)
      p=DNSQuery(data1)
      udps.sendto(p.respuesta(ip), addr)
      print 'Respuesta: %s -> %s' % (p.dominio, ip)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Finalizando'
    udps.close()
```

Comment: You cannot do this with a high-level socket connection. However, it is possible if you access the Hardware tab. The Client connection will close after receiving the first packet, and you will send the second data into space.